# SQL students mark query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How can I select marks of a student who not marked in some sub lessons

```
edu_submark:
Id      sm_mark sub_lesson_id    st_id  course_id
1       97       1               9      3
2       66       2               9      3
3       22       2               1012   3
4       32       1               1012   3
1002    15       1               13     3

edu_sub_lesson:
Id      sl_title            lesson_id
1       Active Directory        2
2       Win7                    2
2009    UI                      1
2011    Win SERVER 2008 R2      2
```

I used this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.sl_title, b.sm_mark 
FROM  
    edu_sublesson a 
LEFT JOIN
    edu_submark b on a.Id = b.sub_lesson_id 
WHERE
    lesson_id = 2 AND course_id = 3 AND st_id = 9
```

result:

```
    Active Directory 99.9
    Win 7            75
```

But I want this result:

```
    Active Directory 99.9
    Win Server       NULL
    Win 7            75
```

- sub_lesson has a foreign key of lesson table and a course has a foreign key of lesson table too.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your WHERE clause from

```
WHERE
    lesson_id = 2 AND course_id = 3 AND st_id = 9
```

to this

```
WHERE
    -- Restrict to specific lesson/course etc..
    (lesson_id = 2 AND course_id = 3 AND st_id = 9)
    -- return any which don't have marks
    OR sm_mark IS NULL
```

Comment: But this query returns All sub_lessons that aren't for a lesson

Comment: lesson_id = 2 <--- It's important

Comment: If that gives you desired results? It wasn't clear which columns in your WHERE clause were coming from which table.

Comment: I want to show marks field in a gridView so teacher can see or edit student marks,
we have course table that have a fk of lesson tbl,
sub_lesson tbl have a fk of lesson,
sub_marks have 3 fk of student,sub_lesson ,course tables

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to

```
SELECT 
    a.sl_title, b.sm_mark 
FROM  
    edu_sublesson a 
LEFT JOIN
    edu_submark b on a.Id = b.sub_lesson_id AND b.course_id = 3 AND b.st_id = 9
WHERE
    a.lesson_id = 2
```

Comment: I want to show marks field in a gridView so teacher can see or edit student marks,
we have course table that have a fk of lesson tbl,
sub_lesson tbl have a fk of lesson,
sub_marks have 3 fk of student,sub_lesson ,course tables

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer now to reflect your table information. You can try the updated query.

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe you should do this:

```
SELECT 
    a.sl_title, b.sm_mark, WinServer, Administration
```

Or whatever names has this fields..